# Asymptotic Distribution of Explosive AR(1) Process

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

I have a question about deriving the asymptotic distribution of an explosive AR(1) process:

$$X_t=\rho X_{t-1}+\epsilon_t; X_0=0; \rho\gt1 $$

In particular, I have been given the following identity, but I do not understand how to derive it. Can anyone lend me a helping hand?

$$\sum_{t=1}^{n} X_{t-1}^2=\frac{1}{\rho^2-1} \left\{X_n^2-\sum_{t=1}^{n}\epsilon^2_t-2\rho\sum_{t=1}^{n}X_{t-1}\epsilon_t \right\} $$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is ordinary algebra: the fact that the $X_t$ and $\epsilon_t$ are random variables is immaterial.  You only need $X_0=0$ (and no restriction on $\rho$) to carry out these simple steps based on the recursive definition of $X_t:$

$$\begin{aligned}
(\rho^2-1)\sum_{t=1}^n X_{t-1}^2 &= \rho^2 \sum_{t=1}^n X_{t-1}^2 -\sum_{t=1}^n X_{t-1}^2\\&= \rho^2 \sum_{t=1}^n X_{t-1}^2 + \left(X_n^2 -\sum_{t=1}^n X_t^2\right)\\
&= \rho^2 \sum_{t=1}^n X_{t-1}^2 + X_n^2 - \sum_{t=1}^n \left(\rho X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t\right)^2  \\
&= \rho^2 \sum_{t=1}^n X_{t-1}^2+ X_n^2 - \sum_{t=1}^n \left(\rho^2 X^2_{t-1} + \epsilon_t^2 + 2\rho X_{t-1}\epsilon_t\right)\\
&= X_n^2 - \sum_{t=1}^n \epsilon_t^2 -2\rho \sum_{t=1}^n X_{t-1}\epsilon_t.
\end{aligned}$$

Because $\rho^2 - 1\ne 0$ you can divide both sides by it, *QED.*

Comment: Re "no" restriction on $\rho$ - we do need to rule out unit root processes, no?

Comment: @Christoph  Doesn't the condition $\rho^2-1\ne 0$ do that? And even when $\rho^2=1,$ we obtain the potentially useful relation $X_n^2 = \sum^n\epsilon_t^2+2\rho\sum^n X_{t-1}\epsilon_t.$  Please bear in mind that this derivation doesn't assume *anything* about the process, or even that this is a process at all: it's solely a property of a sequence of numbers $(X_t), t=0,1,2,\ldots,$ defined recursively from another sequence of numbers $\epsilon_t.$

Comment: Yes, indeed, the condition does that - I was referring to what you wrote in the first paragraph in brackets. Clearly, your derivation "works" for any $\rho$, but I wanted to express that the desired result of the OP seems problematic at $\rho=1$.